# How To Get Tounicode Cmap stream From PDf Using Itext?

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext

I am trying to extract font from pdf for that i got following details in font .

```
 {/LastChar=253, /BaseFont=148 0 R, /Type=/Font, /Subtype=/TrueType, /ToUnicode=149 0 R, /FontDescriptor=150 0 R, /Widths=147 0 R, /FirstChar=32}
```

but `ToUnicode`  is 149 object that contains only `{/Length=785, /Filter=[/FlateDecode]}`
where is Tounicode cmap stream to get  mapping  realation of glyphs and unicodes

Comment: 149 0 obj most likely is a PDF stream of which you only seem to inspect the dictionary part.

Comment: 'PdfObject pp  = reader.getPdfObject(149);
            if( pp.isStream()){
             pr = (PRStream)pp;
             pr.writeContent(new FileOutputStream("hello.txt"));
            }' no stream is printed it is empty

Comment: If the target file exists but is empty, the object is recognized as a stream. Please provide the pdf to inspect.

Comment: based on above values can i generate ttf file

Comment: provide the pdf to inspect , i am unable to do that one please guide me how to do that

Comment: Upload your PDF to some file sharing provider (e.g. Google or Dropbox) and post the link here.

Comment: [pdf link](http://123.176.47.55/DraftRolls/PDFGeneration.aspx?urlPath=D%3a%5C%5CSSR_2013_FINAL+ROLLS%5C%5CAC_238%5C%5CTelugu%5C%5CS01A238P038.PDF)